# Heroku - Apscheduler flask

Tags: python, heroku, scheduler

I have deploy my website to heroku, installed there postgresql database using Python and Flask.
I want to write a function that every week on a spasific day and time will be trigger.
And also another function that triggers everyday on a spasific time.

Since I'm using Heroku, I saw on their documentation that I can use Apscheduler.
In their documentation they display only one example

**Example**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def timed_job():
   print('This job is run every three minutes.')

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=17)
def scheduled_job():
  print('This job is run every weekday at 5pm.')

sched.start()
```

**Link to Heroku website**
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python

This is the only example they present.
So for my question, I want to run a script every week on a spasific day.
I dont know what should i write in the `@sched.scheduled_job('cron', ????? )`.
And also I want to run a script that runs every day on a spasific time.

I did not see any articl or document that explains what parameters I can enter there.

How can I know what I can enter to the `scheduled_job`

Answer (score 0):

You can find more documentation about APScheduler [here](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html).

In your case for every day job at 8:30 you should use

```
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=8, minute=30)
def every_day_job():
    ...
```

For every week job on Monday at 10:45 you should do

```
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon', hour=10, minute=45)
def every_mon_job():
    ...
```